# Manipulate Head based on CMS block

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, blocks

I have a block which I can call by using the following in a CMS page's content:

```
{{block type="karl_catalog/supplier_product" supplier_id="1242" template="karl_catalog/supplier_product.phtml"}}
```

This gets a collection of products and spits them out of the page and is all working fine.

However, I am trying to use an observer to see when this is called as I need to add `rel="next" and rel="prev"` links to the header. I've tried using the `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` observer, but I've been unable to find a way to determine if the block type matches the above block type (above).

```
$l = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
foreach ($l->getAllBlocks() as $block) {
    echo $block->getType();
}
```

The above code echo's the block types, but `karl_catalog/supplier_product` is not shown.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?